# What did the Laser Scan do exactly in Sams eye when he was fighting the Cylons S04E01?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

When the Final 4 out of 5 realize they are Cylons, and Sam is about to get in his Cockpit, he says to the Chief "what if a switch flips in my head, and turns me against my own"

While hes flying around a Cylon fighter does a U turn and scans Sams eye with a bar code Scanner. You later see a a Red flash in his eye.

So my questions is what exactly did that do? i never saw any significance in later episodes, but it looks like i missed something. Did he get an Upgrade or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It didn't affect him directly. However, [this event](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Samuel_Anders#Revelation) more or less directly lead to the civil war/split the cylons went through in the final season. From the [BSG Wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ionian_Nebula):

> The Cylons now suspect that the Final Five reside within the human
>   fleet. Since the Raiders broke off the attack of their own volition, a
>   Cavil decides to have them lobotomized to remove part of their free
>   will. The Four and Five models support that decision, but the Two, Six
>   and Eight models do not. When Sharon Valerii sides with Cavil, he
>   takes that as the deciding vote and has the Raiders lobotomized. In
>   retaliation, a Six named Natalie, now advocating a search for the
>   Five, removes the devices that enslave the Centurions, turning them on
>   Number One's faction (TRS: "Six of One"). This marks the beginning of
>   the Cylon Civil War which forces the rebels and humans to work
>   together in an alliance that ultimately leads to the discovery of
>   Earth and multiple victories over the Ones and their forces.

Comment: I think i understand now, So the raider spins round but doesn't know Sam is a Cylon until after the scan, and then they turn back. You can see why i was confused because you never see the raiders scanning any other pilots. I thought the opposite, that the raider new about Sam. I need to read on those docs. Shame that Blood and Chrome Never took of the ground. I think B-S-C is well made. Thanks.

Comment: let me check, i'm new and don't know how to do that

Comment: ahh ok, the check mark, learn something new every day

Comment: I agree... while it's effects were a little lackluster, B&C could've been a nice addition to the lore. I think it really could've fleshed out and expanded a lot of topics.